# Remove an item from the Toolbar in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plug-in on my site called Airpress. The plugin adds an item to the Admin menu bar in Wordpress that is quite annoying for the many users I have on the site, none of which need it. I isolated the function in the plugin flies, but would like a better solution to disabling it, rather than just commenting out the lines. This is a temporary solution, as it is erased every time the plugin updates. I would prefer to disable the function using my theme’s “functions.php” file. Any suggestions? Here is the code for, the plugin file:

```
function renderDebugToggle( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $args = array(
    'id'    => 'airpress_debugger_toggle',
    'title' => 'Toggle Airpress Debugger',
    'href'  => '#',
    'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-toolbar-page' )
    );
$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );   }
```

Comment: You can also deactivate plugin admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [`remove_node`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) by id. Write the following code in your [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained):

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_airpress_debugger_toggle', 999 );

function remove_airpress_debugger_toggle( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'airpress_debugger_toggle' );
}
```